# How do I read .CHM files in OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, software

What software do I need to open and read a .chm document in OS X?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One of the best apps I've found is [iChm](http://www.robinlu.com/blog/ichm). <s>It has a Spotlight importer as well as the app itself.</s>*  It's free as well as being open source.

Only issue I've had with it is that sometimes long "m dashes", like —, will not be present, and instead the two words will be run together. (Though, I've looked at the source code myself, and it appears to actually be a problem with `libchm`, the open source library that iChm relies on).

*NOTE: the version of iChm in the link above (1.4.2) does *not* have a Spotlight importer, but I've forked this project on GitHub and added a Spotlight importer in version 1.5. You can download 1.5 at http://www.markdouma.com/developer/iChm.zip.

The GitHub project is at https://github.com/NSGod/ichm (it may be a day or so before I've pushed all of the changes).

Answer (score 2):

A little bit googled and find this.

http://chmox.sourceforge.net/

Hope it helps...

Comment: Development of chmox appears to have ceased since 2005. I would recommend using iChm.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple viewers available. [This article](http://maclord.ozarweb.com/mevzu/chm-viewers-for-mac/) lists five.
I've never used any of these myself, but many are free or shareware. Give them a try.

Answer (score 1):

While installing iChm on El Capitan, it was showing me a security warning. So, instead of changing my security settings, I gave [CHM Reader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chm-reader/id424182884?mt=12) from App Store a try. Works well for me.